# Magento 1.9.2 :how to take data though API from android app to magento database?

Tags: magento-1.9, api, sql, json

We are having android app where we are tracking the location and timing of our sales guys! but how we can save this log in time and log out time in magento database ? how I can interact with android app? how to create API to interact with app ?

Answer (score 0):

Magento comes with a **SOAP and REST API** out of the box.

Magento SOAP API: https://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/introduction.html

Magento REST API: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/introduction.html

The REST API does not offer as much functions as the SOAP API so you need to have a look what functions you need.